# Uninstall redmine

Tags: ruby, redmine, uninstallation, purge

I try to uninstall redmine :

```
apt-get purge redmine
```

But i have this error :

```
 apt-get purge redmine
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Les paquets suivants seront ENLEVÉS :
  redmine*
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 1 à enlever et 7 non mis à jour.
Après cette opération, 12,0 Mo d'espace disque seront libérés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer [O/n] ? O
(Lecture de la base de données... 42313 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Suppression de redmine ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/redmine.prerm: line 27: /usr/share/dbconfig-common/dpkg/prerm: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
dpkg : erreur de traitement de redmine (--purge) :
 le sous-processus script pre-removal installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
configured to not write apport reports
                                      Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 redmine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Do you know how to remove it ?

I have also this :

```
root@ks3309528:~# aptitude search ~b
pB  librack-ruby1.8                                                             - A modular Ruby webserver interface (Ruby 1.8)
Bd  redmine                                                                     - flexible project management web application
cB  rubygems1.8                                                                 - package management framework for Ruby libraries/applications
```

Comment: That would be easier if your system locale would be in english...

Comment: Really don't know, why unix users uses localizations

Answer (score 0):

You could try with dpkg directly:

```
dpkg purge redmine
```

alternatly aptitude has a verbose option, you might get a better idea of what's goin wrong:

```
aptitude -v purge redmine
```

Answer (score 0):

Redmine is not just a "package".

It's a web-service, so first of all, try to stop web-service (httpd passenger, or native web-daemon), than check dependencies (ruby gems) and than try to purge "package" via dpkg.

Answer (score 0):

Try running aptitude with -f to clear out the broken package:

```
sudo aptitude -f
```